# Entity Framework adds non existing column to query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF6.1.3. I have 3 poco's pickbatch, order, orderline.

```
public class PickBatch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public string Picker { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Boxes
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderLines = new List<OrderLines>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PickBatchId { get; set; }
    public string OrderType { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLines
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; }
    public string ArticleDescription { get; set; }
    public int QtyOrdered { get; set; }
    public int QtyDelivered { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public string Picker { get; set; }
    public string PickLocation { get; set; } 
    public string Sorting { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; } 
}
```

Not all the properties match the column names in the tables. So on model creating i am fixing this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PickBatch>().ToTable("PickBatch");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PickBatch>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PickBatch>().Property(b => b.Id).HasColumnName("PickBatchId");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Property(b => b.Id).HasColumnName("OrderId");


        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>().Property(o => .Id).HasColumnName("OrderLineId");  

    }
```

When retrieve the orderlines I get an execption: Invalid column name 'PickBatch_Id'. I don't understand why does EF want to add this property?

Comment: May be exception occurs, when you retrive `Boxes`? This class has `PickBatchId ` property, but actually it is not `FK` to `PickBatch`, that is why `PickBatch_Id` appears. To fix, it add `public PickBatch PickBatch { get; set; }`.

Comment: This makes no difference. Outcome is still the same.